# Start kubernetes job programmatically from a pod inside the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, .net-8.0

I am trying to start a kubernetes (AKS) job programmatically, using the dotnet kubernetes client

```
//F#
let startJob (yaml: string) = task {
    let config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.InClusterConfig()
    let job = KubernetesYaml.Deserialize<V1Job>(yaml)

    use client = new Kubernetes(config)
    let! _ = client.BatchV1.DeleteNamespacedJobAsync(job.Name(), job.Metadata.Namespace())
    let! _ = client.BatchV1.CreateNamespacedJobAsync(job, job.Namespace()) }
```

This code is run in a pod inside the cluster and it is supposed to launch a job. The job works normally when started using kubectl.

On the first call (client.BatchV1.DeleteNamespacedJobAsync) I get the following exception:

> "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."

> "The remote certificate was rejected by the provided
> RemoteCertificateValidationCallback."

I couldn't find examples on how to fix this. The examples I saw are all running outside the cluster and using the file kubectl config (KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile()).

Can someone shed some light on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Pods in a cluster don't have the same permissions as an external client using kubectl. The solution is to add to the cluster the appropriate authorization resources. The following manifest applied to the cluster fixed the issue.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: yatp-role
  namespace: yatp
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "batch"]
  resources: ["jobs"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete", "describe"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: yatp-role-binding
  namespace: yatp
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: yatp-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: yatp
```

After this, every container running in a pod in namespace yatp can manipulate jobs in the cluster using the client SDK.